# OAuth authentication for OneLogin overview

Tags: oauth, onelogin

I had a general overview question about OneLogin OAuth authentication.  We are looking to use OneLogin and their OAuth API for authentication and I had questions about the process and the OneLogin App catalog.

Do you have to register the integration / application with the OneLogin catalog?  Is the OneLogin app catalog just a area where "certified" applications are listed?

I saw some language saying: "Depending on the volume of requests, the process to create an app connector and get your app into our catalog takes 2-3 weeks."

So, I am curious if that means we can't deploy the solution until the application is in the OneLogin app catalog.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Register a custom app in the catalog take time: recollect data, decide what template use, test it. There are a lot of requests for new custom apps, that why takes 2-3 time to get them registered.

Meanwhile you register a custom application on Onelogin's catalog, you can use a [Test Connector](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector). Find more info about the [app integration](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/201173334-Introduction-to-App-Integration)

> create an app connector and get your app into our catalog takes 2-3
>   weeks.

Comment: Thank you.  Just to be clear.  We will be using the API integration with the session token process and not SAML.  But the type of integration does not change the fact that you have to register our application.  Any use of OneLogin for remote authentication requires the application to be registered.   We can do development with a test app but can not go live until our app is registered.

Comment: That does help.  I think we have decided to go with the API implementation: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/getting-started/dev-overview for now.   

The first first step is to create a developer account: https://www.onelogin.com/developer-signup

Comment: The first step is create a developer account: https://www.onelogin.com/developer-signup which gives us access to 3 applications and 25 users.  Then how do we upgrade to production account, our partner has 100+ user that we want to authenticate at OneLogin?

After all this, we can work to get our application registered with OneLogin so that it is available on the Secure SSO Portal.

Sound like I have the right steps?

Answer (score 0):

By oAuth do you mean OpenID connect or are you trying to do a three-legged oAuth to get an API access key?

If it's the latter, we don't support that. For security reasons we only support admins creating client-ids/secrets with hard-coded (at creation time) scopes.

If it's the former please take a look at the OIDC documentation for how to configure an application. https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect

At this time, each application instance has it's own, generated clientid & secret.

Either way, you'll need to configure your application to accept the client id & secret that are generated in OneLogin.